# Are rank and determinantal rank the same over a PID?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Are the notions of rank and determinantal rank equivalent for an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in a principal ideal domain $D$?  I'm specifically interested in the case $D=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by the rank of $A$ you mean the rank of the image of (the linear map associated to) $A$, then they are equal. Note that the rank of $A$ is not affected by changes of the bases, so one can assume that $A$ is in its [Smith Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). Since the invariant factors of $A$ are computed by using the minors of $A$ the conclusion follows.